# Inherit Button From Picking Stock Form View Odoo 12

Tags: odoo-12

i want to make inherit for button on stock picking view form odoo 12 (i have been make it on sale order and purchase order, its fixed), the code is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <odoo>
     <record id="stock_picking_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">stock.picking.form</field>
        <field name="model">stock.picking</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_picking_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//button[@name='button_validate']" position ="before">
                <button name="action_confirm" string="Batalkan" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
            </xpath>

        </field>
    </record>
  </odoo>
```

but the button of "Batalkan" not show, even if i use before or after on attribute position.

Comment: The code is working fine, maybe you forgot to add it to the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

dionpamungkas

On this view there has two `button_validate` button, so you can choose your customize button from this two-button.

```
<xpath expr="//button[@name='button_validate'][hasclass('oe_highlight')]" position="before">
    <button name="action_confirm" string="Batalkan" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
</xpath>
<xpath expr="//button[@name='button_validate'][hasclass('o_btn_validate')]" position="before">
    <button name="action_confirm" string="Batalkan" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
</xpath>
```

Thanks